# Property error in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

In .h:

```
interface .... {
   int CatID;
   ... 
}
@property (readwrite) int CatID;

.m:
// Already includes the header file (.h) 
implementation ... {
   @synthesize CatID;
....
   - (void)setCatIDa:(int)cid {
       self.CatID = 20;

       NSLog(@"cat id: %d", CatID); // this returns 20
   }

   - (IBAction)someTest:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"cat id: %d", CatID); // returns 0
   }

}
```

How come its returning 0?

Also the NIB views are changing between the set and get

Comment: You'd better post the code in which you do call the setter/getter.
Why are you doing another setter and calling it with another name?

Comment: setCatIa is just for explanation of the problem and self.CatID sets the int right?

Comment: What do you mean by "// in another..."?

Comment: Just another method after that

Comment: Are you sure `-setCatIDa:` is called before `-someTest:` on the same instance? You could try logging the instance as well.

Comment: Hm, what do you mean with the nib views changing then? It sounds like you actually call `someTest` on a different instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the complete code I can't see exactly what would cause that behaviour, but I would point out a couple of things that *could* be improved and *may* have an impact.

- The property definition doesn't include (assign) - it's likely defaulted, but i'd include it just in case. So @property (assign, readwrite) NSInteger catId;
- The iVar's name starts with an upper case character - it's an instance, so lowercase should be used. @synthesize catId;
- When referencing it, use self.catId

If you could post the completed interface and implementation it'd be easier to test. I've written something very similar here and it works fine...

Comment: assign is the default.  His property declaration is OK.  There's also nothing wrong with using int as the property type.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the assign jeremy. Oh, and I didn't mean to suggest int *was* wrong - I simply wasn't paying that much attention to it when re-writing.

Comment: My money is on it needing to be `self.CatID` for access to work correctly. I also agree the property should start with lowercase, but I don't think it is the issue right now.

Comment: @theMike: In the class `CatID` works just fine, you just directly use the ivar instead of the generated setter/getter.

Comment: @George Then why have I had problems when trying to access a property directly from with in the class myself? Happens pretty much all the time.

Comment: @theMike: I can't know without seeing example code, but the synthesized accessors just use the instance variables themselves. There might be cases where you shadow the ivars with local variables, etc.